# Django queryset filter for backwards related fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can you filter a model based on a model that relates to it?  Example below...this works, but I think this hits the DB twice and is pretty inelegant.  Is there a way to do it directly with querysets?  Maybe somehow with `select_related()`, but haven't been able to figure that one out.  I want to return a `QuerySet` of `Project`.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    pass

class Project(models.Model):
    pass

class Action(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

# Better way to do this?
def projects_by_person(person):
    actions = Action.objects.filter(person=person)
    project_ids = actions.values_list('project')
    return Project.objects.filter(id__in=project_ids)
```

Comment: Actually, this should only be a single database hit, as the filter will be done as a sub query. Nevertheless, using the double underscore syntax as Raunak suggests is a better bet.

Comment: Good to know.  The join should perform a bit faster than the in (...) subquery.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this. I haven't tested it let me know if you have any issues

```
#Untested Code
Project.objects.filter(action__person = person)
```

Comment: Did not realize that you could use the related field for filtering.  Simple and elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is it true that you have a many-to-many relation between `Person` and `Project`? If so, you can simplify your setup like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)     # just an example

class Project(models.Model):
    # ... some fields here ...
```

You can then e.g. issue the following query to get all the projects from people who are called John:

```
Project.objects.filter(person_set__name="John")
```

The usage of `select_related()` can speed up the lookup a bit when you have lots of queries which follow relations between different database tables but you don't need it to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but the Person model isn't really tied just to projects.  Those models are fairly contrived simply for giving the example without a bunch of unrelated boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my case at below:

There are teachers and courses. Teachers can have multiple course but course has done by only one teacher.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    -------

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ------
```

Inside the individual Teacher page I want to list all courses given by this individual teacher. You can find the related view function below.

```
def teacher(request, teacher_id):
teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, pk=teacher_id)
courses = Course.objects.filter(teacher = teacher)

context = {
    'teacher': teacher,
    'courses': courses
}
```